# How to solve a probability problem with 3 random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

I've never done a question with 3 random variables before. Does anyone have an idea of how to start this problem, or what equation to use, or the topic I should search up to learn it? Thanks.
[image]

Edit:
I got something like this, but dont'w know to to advance any further. any suggeestion?
[image]
or am i doing this wrong?

Comment: The random variable $Y$ is a 'mixture'  of three _normal_ random variables. The Wikipedia link in my Comment explains that this $Y$ is also normal.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** You have not shown any of your own work on this problem. I will try to get you started with parts (a) and (b), hoping you can then do (c) and (d) on your own.

*To keep your question from being downvoted and closed, please edit it to show some of your preliminary results.*

Because $A$ and $X$ both take only two values, there are (at most) four possible values for $AX.$ How about staring by listing the four possibilities and using independence to evaluate the probabilities of each. Then the normal 'fade' will cause variability around each possible value. Please edit any success you have into your question.

The simulation in R below with, $p=.6,$ of many realizations of $Y$ will give you close estimates
of $E(Y), Var(Y),$ and the distribution of $Y.$ You can compare simulation results
with your analytical results. [You can expect about two-place accuracy from the simulation.]

```
set.seed(2010)
m = 10^6
x = rbinom(m, 1, .6)
a = sample(c(-1,1), m, rep=T)
n = rnorm(m)
y = a*x + n
summary(y); sd(y)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-5.759375 -0.877927  0.000663  0.001367  0.878451  5.484803 
[1] 1.265227   # aprx SD(Y) = 1.2649
sqrt(1.6)
[1] 1.264911

var(a*x)
[1] 0.6004036  # aprx Var(AX)
var(n)
[1] 1.001982   # aprx Var(N)
table(x*a)/m

      -1        0        1 
0.300690 0.399596 0.299714
```

It seems that $AX$ takes values $-1, 0, 1$ with probabilities $0.3, 0.6, 0.3,$
respectively.

```
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Looking at the histogram, along with the density function of a normal
distribution with the appropriate mean and variance, one might guess
that $Y$ is [normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Mixtures_within_a_parametric_family). According to a Shapiro-Wilk test,
the first 5000 simulated values of $Y$ are consistent with a random
sample from a normal distribution. [The S-W test in R will handle at
most 5000 observations.]

```
shapiro.test(y[1:5000])

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  y[1:5000]
W = 0.99953, p-value = 0.2663
```